# Can we run a single container over multiple machines (hosts)?

Tags: docker, containers, distributed-computing

I just want to know .. Is there any kind of facility available now in docker. I have already gone through some of the documentations in docker regarding the multi-host facility such as,

- Docker swarm
- Docker service (with replicas)

And also I am aware about the `volume` problems in swarm mode and the maximum resource (RAM and CPU) limit to a container will vary and depends upon where (at what machine) it assigned by the `swarm manager`. So here my question is,

- How to run a single container instance over multiple machines (not as service) ? (This means a single container can acquire all resources [RAM1 + RAM2 + ... + RAMn] over these connected machines)
- is there any way to achieve this ?

My question may be idiotic. But I am curious to know.. how to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is `No`. Containerization technologies cannot handle compute, network and storage resources across cluster as one unit. They're only orchestrate them.

Docker and Co. based on cgroup, namespaces, layered FS, virtual networks, etc. All of them wired to specific machine + running processes and requiring additional servicing to manage containers not only on concrete machine, but in the cluster(For example, Mesos, k8s or Swarm).

You can check products such as Hadoop, Spark, Cassandra, Akka framework and other distributed computation implementations to see examples how to manage cluster resources as one unit.

PS You should always think about increasing system complexity with rising of components distribution.